# Responsive Container not among each other when too small

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have three cols with text and a background color in it. When the window gets smaller, the three cols are getting too slim but I want them to place among each other. How do I make this responsive?

I tried putting the three cols in a row class but then the background color are getting extended

```html
<div class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="textbox">
      <p> Text </p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="textbox">
      <p> Text</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="textbox">
      <p>Text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

```css
.textbox {
    min-height: 490px;
    background: #F6F6F6;
    padding: 0 28px;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

I expected the three textboxes to place among each other when they are getting too small

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap V4.X then the `col-xs-4` doens't exist anymore. ([link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#grid-system))

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you're going for here, but it sounds like you want your columns to stack when the browser gets smaller. In that case, since you're using Bootstrap, I'd recommend using flexbox classes, like this:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="textbox">
    <p> Text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <p> Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the Bootstrap [documentation on flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex).

Also, this is a great [guide for using native CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) properties.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried using those classes but It did not work. They are still not among each other :/

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are you trying to keep the columns so that they stay next to one another horizontally as the view-port shrinks? If so you could try removing the .flex-wrap class.